# displayName is not set outside commit changes with completion

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

When setting the displayName for a user in Firebase, the change is being set within the commitChangesWithCompletion block but not outside.  Does anyone know what is going on and how to get the displayName set outside?

The code is in Swift and looks like this:

```
    func updateDisplayName(user: FIRUser?) {
        let changeRequest = user!.profileChangeRequest()
        changeRequest.displayName = userName    // userName is Gandalf
        changeRequest.commitChangesWithCompletion(){ (error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            print("userName inside commit: \(user?.displayName)")
        }
        print("userName outside commit: \(user?.displayName)")
    }
```

When I run the code, the second print is called first.
 1. userName outside commit: nil
 2. userName inside commit:    Optional("Gandalf")

When I look later in my code to see if this a latency issue, the displayName stays nil

Comment: I haven't worked on Firebase but seeing your code, it seems the changeRequest is an API call and it is asynchronous, so it is executed instantly and waiting for the request to complete. Before request gets complete, the outside print statement is called and then once the request is completed, the internal print is called.

Comment: The db communication is asynchronous but as I said it's not down to latency problems inside and outside the block. If I test the display name later in my code, it remains nil. The work around I've found is to place the rest of my code within the block, but it's very strange.